# How does my loop return 100? I’m confused

Tags: javascript

```js
const array = [1,100,2,6]
function biggestNumberInArray(arr) {
    let highest = 0;
    for (item of arr) {
         if (highest < item) {
            highest = item;
        }
    }
     return highest;
}

console.log(biggestNumberInArray(array))
```

How does this return 100?
I mean the variable highest is always lesser than item. Please explain me

Comment: What does the line `highest = item` do?

Comment: 100 is the biggest number so why wouldn't it be 100

Comment: @Peter T Walker yes but the if statement makes me confuse

Comment: Hi, the if statement is checking if highest, which by default is 0, is less than the current item in the iteration through the array. So in the first iteration it checks `0 < 1`, thats  true so highest = 1, then in the second iteration it checks `1 < 100`, which is true, so highest = 100, then `100 < 2` which is false, so the code below the if statement is not run

Comment: Just switch the direction of the comparison and think "if the current number is higher than the previously highest number, it becomes the new highest number"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your code works is that it has a max variable that is set to 0, which is the lowest possible number.

Then, as you loop through the array, if the max variable finds a number bigger than itself, it will change its value to become that number. That is the code you are talking about:

```
    if (highest < item) {
        highest = item;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your iterating an array of numbers and comparing each element to the variable highest. Highest is updated when compared to an element greater than highest... the function returns the highest number in the array

Answer (score 0):

This is because `highest` starts at `0` (which is assumed to always be lowest than all array numbers). if there's an item which is greater than the current highest, it saves it's value it the `highest` variable.

please notice that your function only works for arrays who doesn't include only negative numbers (in that case it will always return zero).

if you want to find the highest number in an array i would suggest the following using [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and the [`...` spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

`Math.max(...arr);`

Answer (score 0):

1st iteration `highest=1` because 0 < 1

2nd iteration `highest=100` because 1 < 100

3rd iteration `highest=100` because 100 > 2 that's why if condition will not execute. Same goes for 4th iteration

That's why function return 100